# Cannot read file /usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig when try to run gradle build

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

I keep having this error message when I try to run the `gradle build` using command line, while no issues at all using IntelliJ.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'xxxxx'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'net.vivin.gradle-semantic-build-versioning']
  >   **> Unable to find Git repository: Systen wide config file /usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig is invalid org.eclipse.jgit.errors.ConfigInvalidException: Cannot read file /usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig**

The repository has been specified in the `build.gradle` file and build works fine with IntelliJ.

```
maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
}
```

I am not sure why it tries to check the `gitconfig` file and why it failed. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle` file or at least your dependency list?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found two ways to workaround it. I'm not saying I've fixed it because it seems this is an unhandled edge case on one of my gradle dependencies.

What I believe is the issue: `org.eclipse.jgit` doesn't know how to parse the [include] section on a `gitconfig` file.

Workaround #1:

Set the `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM` environment variable. According to [git's docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-GITCONFIGNOSYSTEM) this will:

```
skip reading settings from the system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig file.
```

or

Workaround #2:

Remove the [include] section from your `gitconfig` file, which according to your error message is located at `/usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig`.